# Having trouble in in Json parsing and save value in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am getting json response from my server like this . I want to save all this value in database via mysql-PHP . Please Help .

```
{"fields":[{"label":"Do you have a   website?","field_type":"website","required":false,"field_options":{},"cid":"c1"},{"label":"Security personnel #82?","field_type":"radio","required":true,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"Yes","checked":false},{"label":"No","checked":false}],"include_other_option":true},"cid":"c10"},{"label":"Medical history","field_type":"file","required":true,"field_options":{},"cid":"c14"}]}
```

Comment: Try writing code to save it to your database :)

Comment: There is no shortage of PHP + MySQL tutorials out there. (Although try finding one that doesn't use the deprecated `mysql_` API).

Answer (score 1):

You would first have to encode that json object, if you already havent,

then escape the quotes with mysqli_real_escape_string() -php

and then insert it into database.

For more information consult google.com